# Is there a way to Increase the "Thickness" of an Empty?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, empty

The empties are really thin and hard to see sometimes. Is there a way to increase the thickness of the empties?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't increase the thickness *per se* but you can use another object as a proxy easily with the collection instance feature.

Create a new collection, add an object inside it eg a simple Icosphere, reset its location with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, add a Wireframe modifier.

In the empty object properties, expand the *Instancing* panel and select your newly created collection.

[image]

You can also use a Grease Pencil object, or any other type of object.

[image]

[image]

Don't forget to disable rendering it you don't want it to appear in your renders.

[image]